# OpenCV - How to translate a pixel-following contour to vertex-following contour

Tags: opencv, svg, image-processing, contour

I am using `cv2.findContours`. The retrieved contours are 'pixel following' (fig a). I then save them as `svg` polygon elements.

My problem is that `svg` polygons are interpreted as 'vertex-following' in a naive way (fig b is the wanted solution). Thus I lose single files of pixels on the right and on the bottom, as "mid-pixel" coordinates are interpreted as upper-left corner coordinates.

How can i translate my contour from pixels to vertices (corners) or otherwise get a vertex-following contour that would be pixel accurate?

My code is [HERE](https://github.com/eyaler/blob2svg)

[image]

Comment: It seems to me if you duplicated all the pixels to the right, down and to the "south east", then ran your contour algorithm, you would get the outline you need.

Comment: this wont work as it could close one pixel wide gaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it by:

1. zooming the image x2
2. finding contours
3. dividing the contour points by 2 and rounding up